# how to change background color in ios game development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am just new to `cocos2d`. I just want to change the background color and want to set any image. I refer code from [This Tutorial.](http://code4app.net/ios/Plane-game-by-cocos2d/5178a5756803fac256000003)

And also could not find where is all images in `game-art.plist`. I could not find any of them. just check this link and give me an appropriate answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For change background color,
You need to change:

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer <.....
```

to:

```
@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayerColor <.....
```

And Then in the `HelloWorldLayer.m`

change:

```
if( (self=[super init]) ) {
```

to:

```
if((self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(125,200,255,255)])) /// set ccc4(... as you want
{
```

**For Add Image as BackGround.**

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
[self addChild:background];
```

Comment: couldn't change background color . i  use your code but no result

Comment: did you try to change the color of background color

Comment: @user3218052 - try with `if((self = [super initWithColor:ccc4(125,200,255,255)]))`

Comment: i tried but only black color appear

Comment: can i put any image instead of color?

Comment: I tried with above code, it's working for me :)

Comment: You have a help vampire on you iPatel.

Comment: @trojanfoe - what do you mean ?? any thing is wrong >??

Comment: Never mind.  It looked like you had someone asking question after question in order to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

follow this http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/cocos2d-scenes-and-layers

class Name : HelloWorldScene

```
  (id)init {
      self = [super init];
      if (!self) return(nil);
      //create your bg sprite
      CCScene *scene = [CCScene node]; HelloWorld *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

      CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"cartoon_landscape.png"]; 
      [layer addChild:background];
  }
```

follow this for more help.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/cocos2d

Comment: in which class i have to  use this code?

Comment: ok i clearify you that i am using this code in +()scene method.not in init method